# How to resolve an incomplete \iffalse error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I'm trying to create a multitude of 8x8 grids with a single random shaded box on each. This is for a classroom activity and I want a bunch of different grids and would rather not hard-code the random box for each one. I'm using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.54cm, y=2.54cm]
    \foreach \y in {1,2,...,8}
    {
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}
        {
            \ifthenelse{\x= \pgfmathparse{random(8)}\pgfmathresult \AND \y=\pgfmathparse{random(8)}\pgfmathresult}
            {\filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x,\y) rectangle (1+\x,1+\y);}
            {\draw[black] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x,\y) rectangle (1+\x,1+\y);}
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I get the error

> Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 51"

where line 51 is that close curly brace before the `\end{tikzpicture}`. I've looked around for a fix but haven't discovered one yet.

Comment: you can't do `x= \pgfmathparse{random(8)}\pgfmathresult` the equality test can only test values (via expansion) it can not do complicated assignments to temporary macros. You need to do the `\pgfmathparse` first outside the if, then test the values

Comment: actually if you only want one shaded square you need to do get the random x and y coordinate outside both for loops, as it you are generating random numbers every time

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet compilable?

Comment: Since you're using pgfmath anyway, you can do the conditional evaluation using its functions and don't need `\ifthenelse` at all.

Answer (score 4):

Just fleshing out David's comments.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.54cm, y=2.54cm]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RandomX}{random(8)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RandomY}{random(8)}
    \foreach \y in {1,2,...,8}
    {
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}
        {
            \ifthenelse{\x=\RandomX  \AND \y=\RandomY}
            {\filldraw[draw=black,fill=lightgray] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x,\y) rectangle (1+\x,1+\y);}
            {\draw[black] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x,\y) rectangle (1+\x,1+\y);}
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And @cfr is right, but this also works.

Answer (score 3):

It seems easier to draw the grid first and then shade a random box as then you don't need to have a conditional statement. The following code defines a macro `\RandomSquareInGrid` that shades a random square in a square grid. By default, an `8x8` grid is drawn but there is an optional argument to change the grid size. When I ran the MWE below I got
[image]

but as the shaded square is chosen randomly the output should change.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\parindent=0pt

\newcommand\RandomSquareInGrid[1][8]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,x=2.54cm, y=2.54cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,#1} {% draw the grid
      \draw(\x,0) -- ++(0,#1);
      \draw(0,\x) -- ++(#1,0);
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xrnd{random(#1)}% choose a random square to shade
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yrnd{random(#1)}
    \draw[fill=lightgray](\xrnd,\yrnd) rectangle ++ (-1,-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

  \RandomSquareInGrid \quad
  \RandomSquareInGrid \quad
  \RandomSquareInGrid

  \RandomSquareInGrid[4] \quad
  \RandomSquareInGrid[10]

\end{document}
```

Actually, rather than drawing the grid by "by hand", as I have done, one should perhaps use the `tikz` grid command. Note that I have added `scale=0.2` only to make it easier to see the output.